# Total price calculation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Am trying to multiply two cells in HTML table. Here below the code I created:

```js
function multiply() {
    var u_price = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("u-price"));
    var s_meter = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("s-meter"));
    var t = u_price * s_meter;
    document.getElementById("tot-price").value = t.toFixed(3);
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-box" name="u-price" value="0" onKeyUp="multiply();"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-box" name="s-meter" value="1" onKeyUp="multiply();"></td>
  <td><input type="text" class="input-box" name="tot-price" id="tot-price" disabled></td>
</tr>
```

The value returned is NaN.

[image]

Can you please advise on how to handle this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements, and a collection is not parseable to float

Comment: Step 1 when trying to use a function: Read the manual for the function you're using and take note of what the function returns: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName . In this case it would make more sense to give the elements each a unique ID and get them by ID. Also you need to get the `.value` (as per your later usage of getElementById) not the element itself.

Comment: Also as a wider point, get out of the habit of using legacy inline event handlers in the HTML, and learn to use addEventListener to create more maintainable code.

Answer (score 1):

A couple changes needed:

1. `getElementsByName` returns an array of elements matching the name parameter.
   So if you're using this method, you should change it to `getElementsByName[0]` and make sure you only have one element that matches (i.e. - no other elements with a matching name).
2. You forgot `.value`

So your function should look like this -

```js
function multiply() {
    var u_price = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("u-price")[0].value);
    var s_meter = parseFloat(document.getElementsByName("s-meter")[0].value);
    var t = u_price * s_meter;
    document.getElementById("tot-price").value = t.toFixed(3);
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a (live) NodeList, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByName` returns an array of elements by that name and hence we need to access the **value** of the **first** element of that array.

Instead of `document.getElementsByName("u-price")`,

You will have to use `document.getElementsByName("u-price")[0].value` to get the value.

Comment: Sidenote: [getElementsByName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) returns a (live) NodeList, not an array.

Comment: You're right. I described it in simpler terms because it also accepts array operations and can be converted as well.